# Why do recent launch vehicles like that of Space X and Rocket Lab have far fewer umbilicals than before? What has changed?

Tags: spacex, launch, rockets, falcon-9

Launch vehicles using mobile launch pads have many umbilical connections, whereas the ones using TEL launch structure with strongback, don't. Why is that?

As seen in the picture, Electron has just one main umbilical:

[image]
<sub>[Source.](https://spacenews.com/rocket-lab-electron-launch-fails/)</sub>

Comment: Well, USB-C can do pretty much anything these days...

Comment: @JonCuster made me laugh, now people are looking...

Comment: Comparing an Electron or Falcon to a Saturn V or Space Shuttle is not really an honest comparison, as these launch vehicles serve vastly different types of missions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at what [umbilicals are on SLS](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/fs-2018-02-250-ksc-ml_umbilical_fact_sheet.pdf), a fairly traditional and very large rocket. It has two stages and two boosters and a crewed capsule. It uses cryogenic liquid oxygen and hydrogen for fuel.

- > Two aft skirt electrical umbilicals, or ASEUs, will connect to the SLS rocket at the bottom outer edge of each booster and provide electrical power and data connections  to  the  SLS  rocket  until  it  lifts  off  from  the launch pad. The ASEUs will act like a telephone line and carry a signal to another subsystem on the mobile launcher called the Launch Release System.
- > Two aft skirt purge umbilicals, or ASPUs, also will connect to the SLS rocket at the bottom outer edge of each booster to remove potentially hazardous gases and maintain temperature range of components  through  a  heated  gaseous  nitrogen  purge  to  the  cavity of each booster’s aft skirt
- > Two tail service mast umbilicals, or TSMUs, will connect from the zero-level deck on the mobile launcher to the SLS rocket core stage aft section. The TSMUs are about 33 feet tall. They will  provide  liquid  oxygen  and  liquid  hydrogen  fluid  lines  and  electrical cable connections to the SLS core stage engine section  to  support  propellant  handling  during  prelaunch  operations.
- > The core stage inter-tank umbilical, or CSITU, is a swing arm umbilical that will connect to the SLS core stage inter-tank. The inter-tank  umbilical’s  main  function  is  to  vent  gaseous  hydro-gen from the core stage. The arm also provides conditioned air, pressurized gases and power and data connection to the core stage.
- > The  core  stage  forward  skirt  umbilical,  or  CSFSU,  is  located  at the 180-foot level on the mobile launcher tower, above the liquid oxygen tank. The CSFSU is an umbilical that will swing into position to provide connections to the core stage forward skirt  of  the  SLS  rocket,  and  then  swing  away  before  launch.  CSFSU’s  main  purpose  is  to  provide  conditioned  air/GN2  to  the SLS Core Stage Forward Skirt cavity.
- > The  interim  cryogenic  propulsion  stage  umbilical,  or  ICPSU,  is  located at about the 240-foot level on the mobile launcher tower. The  swing  arm  ICPSU  will  supply  fuel,  oxidizer,  environmental  control  systems,  pneumatics  and  electrical  connections  to  the  interim  cryogenic  propulsion  stage  of  the  SLS  rocket.
- > The Orion service module umbilical, or OSMU, will connect from the mobile launcher tower to the Orion service module. The  umbilical  is  located  at  the  280-foot  level  of  the  tower  and, prior to launch will transfer liquid coolant for the elec-tronics and air for the electronics and purge air/GN2 for the environmental control system to support the spacecraft.
- > The crew access arm, or CAA, is located at the 274-foot level on  the  mobile  launcher  tower.  The  CAA  will  rotate  from  its  retracted  position  and  interface  with  the  SLS  rocket  at  the  Orion  crew  hatch  location  to  provide  entry  in  and  exit  from  the Orion crew module. It will provide a safe and unobstruct-ed  pathway  for  entry  and  exit  during  processing  operations  in the Vehicle Assembly Building, and processing and launch operations at Launch Pad 39B.
- > The vehicle stabilizer system, or VSS, is located at the 200-foot level of the mobile launcher tower, and will provide a structural interface to the SLS core stage. The VSS will help reduce core stage vehicle motion during rollout to the launch pad, process-ing  operations,  high  wind  events  at  the  pad,  and  the  launch  countdown.

In sum...

- Two for power and data to the boosters.
- Two to vent the boosters.
- Two for fueling LOX and LH and more electrics to the boosters.
- One for venting, power, data, and air conditioning to the core.
- One for more aircon/venting of the core.
- One for cryogenics.
- One for the Orion capsule.
- One for the crew.

Electron has two stages with no boosters and an uncrewed payload. It uses non-cryogenic [RP-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RP-1) (liquid kerosene) and liquid oxygen (LOX) as its fuels.

Without the boosters nor a crewed payload module, that leaves just these equivalent umbilicals to supply the SLS core.

- One for venting, power, data, and air conditioning to the core.
- One for more aircon/venting of the core.
- One for cryogenics to the core.
- One for core stabilization.

Unfortunately I don't have details of what's in the Electron umbilical, but we can make a few guesses.

With the Electron rocket being so much smaller, it doesn't need a dedicated stabilizer.

While both Electron and SLS use cryogenics, LOX has a much higher boiling point than the liquid hydrogen used on the SLS. And the much simpler Electron can be stacked and rolled out much faster than the huge and complex SLS, so it spends less time sitting on the pad heating up. The SLS carries 80 tons of fuel, the Electron about 10 tons. It doesn't need as much cryogenics while sitting on the pad, if at all.

With the reduced fuel, reduced size, less need for cryogenics, modern data architecture of the Electron it's not unreasonable that yes, they can compress the three remaining core umbilicals into one.